# how to write a mocha test testing a function

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

if I have this function

```
var a = function() {
      const b = {
        c: {
          myNum: 150,
        }
      }
      return b['c']
    }
    config()
```

what would be the correct test to see if it returns the right thing? 
the test I currently have isn't quite working..

```
describe('A', () => {
  let a;
  a = sinon.stub();
  it('returns the correct number', () => {
    expect(a).to.equal('150');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a stub for this. You need to literally use your function and call it inside the test. So Something like this -

```
it('returns the correct number', () => {
    let result = myFunc(input);
    assert.equal(expectedResult, result);
  });
```

Comment: but when I do that it says, `TypeError: (0 , _a.default) is not a function`. perhaps maybe coz of the way im importing?